# Determine conflict-free sets?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

Suppose you have a bunch of sets, whereas each set has a couple of subsets.

Set1 = { (banana, pineapple, orange), (apple, kale, cucumber), (onion, garlic) }

Set2 = { (banana, cucumber, garlic), (avocado, tomato) }

...

SetN = { ... }

The goal now is to select one subset from each set, whereas each subset must be conflict free with any other selected subset. For this toy-size example, a possible solution would be to select (banana, pineapple, orange) (from Set1) and (avocado, tomato) (from Set2).

A conflict would occur, if one would select the first subset of Set1 and Set2 because the banana would be contained in both subsets (which is not possible because it exists only once).

Even though there are many algorithms, I was unable to select a suitable algorithm. I'm somehow stuck and would appreciate answers targeting the following questions:

1) How to find a suitable algorithm and represent this problem in such a way that it can be processed by the algorithm?

2) How a possible solution for this toy-size example may look like (any language is just fine, I just want to get the idea).

Edit1: I was thinking about simulated annealing, too (return one possible solution). This could be of interest to minimize, e.g., the overall cost of selecting the sets. However, I could not figure out how to make an appropriate problem description that takes the 'conflicts' into account.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the second answer fails to address (1). It represents the input as a set of strings. The author mentioned that it was inefficient because string comparison is slow. To answer your question about 100 collections with 30 sets per collection... I don't think a backtracking algorithm (both solutions presented are the same from what I can tell) would run fast enough. On input that size you might consider machine learning algorithms

Comment: Based on the two suggestions I was now able to implement this using Algorithm X and primary/secondary columns. Based on that, and given the fact that it is the highest-voted answer anyway, I have accepted this solution. The solution in Haskell is correct but not as easily accessible to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem can be formulated as a [generalized exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

Create a new atom for each set of sets (Set1, Set2, etc.) and turn your input into an instance like so:

```
{Set1, banana, pineapple, orange}
{Set1, apple, kale, cucumber}
{Set1, onion, garlic}
{Set2, banana, cucumber, garlic}
{Set2, avocado, tomato}
...
```

making the `Set*` atoms primary (covered exactly once) and the other atoms secondary (covered at most once). Then you can solve it with a generalization of Knuth's Algorithm X.

Comment: was going to ask how you generalize it, but this explains it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Generalizations

Comment: Great, I did not think about "flattening" my sets. Algorithm X indeed appears to be the correct choice. Is there any algorithmic description available that takes these primary and secondary atoms into consideration?

Comment: @user26372 Once you understand [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_Algorithm_X) with primary constraints only, I think it's as simple as modifying step 1 to read "If A has <strike>is empty</strike> has only secondary rows, terminate" and modifying step 2 to read "Choose deterministically a primary row", since your instances have no sets with secondary atoms only.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend your answer a little bit. I especially do not understand two things about Algorithm X: I) "The header for each secondary column should have L and R fields that simply point to itself" -> how to interconnect them with the primary columns / sets then? II) For now, I do not see how it works out for sets with completely different elements in it (e.g., the examples mentioned by Knuth are "symmetric". That's not the case here. This is probably not an issue as soon as I understood I) properly.

Comment: @user26372 I don't see I) of yours in the DLX article on Wikipedia. With generalized algorithm and primary/secondary columns it states a single phrase: **This alters the algorithm's solution test from a matrix having no columns to a matrix having no primary columns, but doesn't require any further changes.** So, secondary columns are still linked with primary ones, it's just "complete solution" check differs. Drop that I) outright.

Comment: My quote was from the original paper. You are absolutely right though and it certainly makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the list of sets, I had the image of a maze with multiple entrances. The task is akin to tracing paths from top to bottom that are free of subset-intersections. The example in Haskell picks all entrances, and tries each path, returning those that succeed.

My understanding of how the code works (algorithm):

For each subset in the first set, pick each subset in the next set where the intersection of that subset with each of the subsets in the accumulated result is null. If there are no subsets matching the criteria, break that strain of the loop. If there are no sets left to pick from, return that result. Call the function recursively for all chosen subsets (and corresponding accumulating-results).

```
import Data.List (intersect)
import Control.Monad (guard)

sets = [[["banana", "pineapple", "orange"], ["apple", "kale", "cucumber"], ["onion", "garlic"]]
       ,[["banana", "cucumber", "garlic"], ["avocado", "tomato"]]]

solve sets = solve' sets [] where
  solve' []         result = [result]
  solve' (set:rest) result = do
    subset <- set
    guard (all null (map (intersect subset) result))
    solve' rest (result ++ [subset])
```

OUTPUT:

```
*Main> solve sets
[[["banana","pineapple","orange"],["avocado","tomato"]]
,[["apple","kale","cucumber"],["avocado","tomato"]]
,[["onion","garlic"],["avocado","tomato"]]]
```

Comment: I was going to say this algorithm doesn't seem very efficient, despite it being elegant. David Eisenstat's link above makes me think that there isn't a known solution that's much faster. Perhaps that's why backtracking is the most popular solution taught for the N-queen's problem (which is apparently a "generalized exact cover problem").

Comment: @roliu yes, what you say could be true. Could you help me/us understand how the backtracking solution is more efficient than this one?

Comment: I like the approach and the idea, though I do not understand the code (yet). I would be interested in the expected runtime as well (vs. Algorithm X). Would it be feasible to run this on approx. 100 sets each of them with approx. 30 subsets?

Comment: @user26372 sure, you could download a haskell platform (http://www.haskell.org/platform/) and replace the example `sets` with whatever you'd like. I'd be happy to try it if you'd like to provide the data somewhere on the web in the same form: `[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[1,2],[5,6]]]` for numbers, `[[["1","2"],["3","4"]], [["1","2"],["5","6"]]]` for strings. The main inefficiencies I see in it are that (1) for each path-tree, comparisons will be repeated (although not for any one path-tree), and (2) I would guess that number comparison would be faster than string comparison.

Comment: @groovy Your solution _is_ a backtracking algorithm... unless I have no idea what I'm talking about. Basically you said you thought of this as a maze. Instead, think of it as a decision tree. A backtracking algorithm is one where you simply perform a DFS, and any time you fail you just go back up (you ignore the subtree rooted at that node because some constraint will fail at _any_ node in that subtree). In your case, you fail at `guard` (I think, at least? I don't know Haskell) and "backtrack". Otherwise you continue performing the DFS. If you reach a leaf node it's a solution.

Comment: @roliu oh, thanks for clarifying. I guess I'm learning more about these things, the more time I spend on SO.

Comment: I have not accepted the answer yet, since it does not fully address 1) (see question). Perhaps you can extend your answer in a more algorithmic way. Well, I guess I have to split the bounty between both of you ...

Comment: @user26372 Oh, I didn't notice you set a bounty. I tried to clarify in the answer my understanding of how the code works (the algorithm). My guess is 100 sets, each with about 30 subsets should be fine. Could you provide a sample somewhere on the web for us to try (hopefully one where at least one solution is possible)?

Comment: I have created some random sets ... let's see if they work: http://pastebin.com/Au7Qn9jc   and   http://pastebin.com/vEThrcCC  and http://pastebin.com/3wuxGXWn  and  http://pastebin.com/fgmRzM5k

Comment: @user26372 do these sets have a solution?

Comment: Probably one of those 4 sets (in particular, the last set).

Comment: @user26372 it's been working for a few minutes and no results yet. Looks like the repeated comparisons and multiple threads slow it down quite a bit, much more than I anticipated, which is something for me to learn from. I hope algorithm x can solve it faster for you. I'll let you know if I get an answer or better answer.

Comment: @user26372 (working with the last list you provided) from 1-54 sets, the solutions are immediate, after that the program begins to slow down.

Comment: @user26372 I noticed that when I ask for only one result ( code: `head $ solve (take 81 sets)` ), the program returns a result for 81 sets in 9.8 seconds. But for 82 sets, its quite a bit longer, which probably means it was lucky to find a solution earlier in the backtracking. If I knew more, perhaps I could implement some memoization to speed it up.